# How to create new users in Gitlab

Tags: mysql, gitlab, ubuntu-server

I've installed gitlab in my ubuntu server, and follow the documentation connect the gitlab to gitlabhq_production in mysql, but the database is an empty one, how to create a new user with it?

PS: I can use root user login the gitlab currently

reference: https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/install/database_mysql.md

Answer (score 0):

the documentation tells you how to create a MySQL user, not a git user.

now I guess you need to connect through the gitlab web page in order to finish your installation.